# second case not firing in PHP switch statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a simple table that query's mysql.  I have text fields that adjust the query.  For example, if I put an `item ID` in, in, and press submit, it will select just that `ID`, but if I hit submit on blank text fields then it should give me all the data.

This works fine on my first case, but I can't get the second one to fire.  If I `switch` places on the cases, then the new one which is in first place will fire now, but the second one won't.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
switch (isset($_POST)) {

case (isset($_POST['ProdNo'])):  // should only fire if the ProdNo field is filled and submit is hit
      if (empty($_POST['ProdNo'])) { break; }  // should return us to a full listing
      $i=$_POST['ProdNo'];
      $sql = "SELECT * from fg_inventory WHERE ProdNo LIKE '$i%'"; 
      $result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
break;  


case (isset($_POST['fg_inventory_id2'])):   // should only fire if the fg_inventory field is filled and submit is hit
      if (empty($_POST['fg_inventory_id2'])) { break; }  // should return us to a full listing
      $i=$_POST['fg_inventory_id2'];
      $sql = "SELECT * from fg_inventory WHERE fg_inventory_id2=$i"; 
      $result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
break;

default: 

$sql = "SELECT * from fg_inventory"; 
    $result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
    }
```

Comment: If the first case was fired. The second etc were not going to. That is how switch works. if you want to test both first and second condition.. use 'if'

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will probably create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Putting `$_POST` data directly in the query like you have here is extremely dangerous.

Comment: For your usage, an else-if statement would be much better suited. As per one of the answers, this isn't how switch statements are designed to work.

Comment: Ok, I will switch to If statements, and also look at bind_param

Answer (score 0):

So the switch statement may not be working how you might think it is...

`switch($var)` will compare `$var` against the various `case` blocks. For example,

```
$var = 1;
switch($var) {
    case (1): // Is $var equal to 1?
        echo("ONE");
        break;
    case (2): // Is $var equal to 2?
        echo("TWO");
        break;
}
```

This case would output `ONE`.

Since you're using `switch` with `isset`, you're always going to be passing in a `true` or `false`. Your following `case` checks will also be checking for either `true` or `false`. So in the end you're going to be checking `trues` against `falses`. In this case you should probably just be using nested `if` statements. :-)

Here's PHP's [switch reference page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

Also note that if you want one case to fall through to another, just omit the `break;`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong usage of switch. Switch takes a variable and then compares each case it could be. An example would be

```
switch ($variable) {
case "hello":
//do something
break;

case "world":
break;
```

In other words, the case is what the variable would be equal to, to trigger what's inside it. You're just asking if $_POST exists, which it always does, so switch ($_POST) always equals true. The first case always equals true, too, so... that's what's firing. You want to use if(isset($_POST['something'])) {}else{}

Comment: `$_POST` does not always exist.  If a form wasn't posted, it will be null.  (Not sure about if the form is submitted but empty (no named, enabled inputs in the form).)  But an empty string is a value, so `$_POST` will exist if there's an enabled text box.